# Calculate load based on value return 0 or NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

User will enter three values quantity, load, duration and then click on total button to show the multiplication in the watt hour `textbox`. But I always ended up getting a 0 or `NaN`.I tried with input `type="number"` but always getting the same result. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var quantityval = parseInt($("#quantity").text(), 10);
var wattsval = $("#wattage option:selected").val();
var duration = parseInt($("#duration_use").text(), 10);

$("#total").click(function() {
  var totalval = (quantityval * wattsval) * duration;
  $("#watt-hour").val(totalval);
  console.log($("#watt_hour").val(totalval));
});
```

```html
<table class="table-bordered table table-md text-center table-responsive table-lg" id="table">

  <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Load Type</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Wattage (W)</th>
      <th>Duration Use</th>
      <th>Watt Hour</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="bg-success">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <select class="form-control" id="type">
<option>Fan</option>
<option>Iron</option>
<option>Blub</option>
<option>Motor</option>
<option>AC</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="10px" class="form-control" id="quantity" /></td>
      <td>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="wattage" id="wattage" placeholder="Enter Consumption in Watts" class="form-control"> -->
        <select class="form-control" id="wattage">
<option>25</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>
<option>80</option>
<option>100</option>
<option>120</option>
<option>1000</option>
<option>1500</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>2500</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="10px" class="form-control" id="duration_use" /></td>
      <td><textarea size="10px" class="form-control" id="watt_hour" style="height: 38px;overflow: hidden;resize: none;"></textarea></td>
      <td><button id="total" class="btn-success btn" style="padding: 5px">Total</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: immediate guess I'm going to go with the fact that you aren't parsing the wattage value to float or integer (whatever you expect it to be)

Comment: Simple debugging using console.log would have found where the issue is with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple issues here,

- use `val` instead of `text`
- directly take the value of `select` instead of its `option`
- Put the fetch of values in the click event
- use `watt_hour` instead of `watt-hour` while setting value.

Make it

```
var quantityval = +$("#quantity").val();
var wattsval = +$("#wattage").val();
var duration = +$("#duration_use").val();
```

**Note**

`parseInt` is fine, I am simply putting unary `+` for keeping it short.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#total").click(function() {
    var quantityval = +$("#quantity").val();
    var wattsval = +$("#wattage").val();
    var duration = +$("#duration_use").val();
    console.log(quantityval, wattsval, duration);
    var totalval = (quantityval * wattsval) * duration;
    console.log(quantityval, wattsval, duration, totalval);
    $("#watt_hour").val(totalval);
    console.log($("#watt_hour").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-bordered table table-md text-center table-responsive table-lg" id="table">

  <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Load Type</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Wattage (W)</th>
      <th>Duration Use</th>
      <th>Watt Hour</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="bg-success">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <select class="form-control" id="type">
<option>Fan</option>
<option>Iron</option>
<option>Blub</option>
<option>Motor</option>
<option>AC</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="10px" class="form-control" id="quantity" /></td>
      <td>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="wattage" id="wattage" placeholder="Enter Consumption in Watts" class="form-control"> -->
        <select class="form-control" id="wattage">
<option>25</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>
<option>80</option>
<option>100</option>
<option>120</option>
<option>1000</option>
<option>1500</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>2500</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="10px" class="form-control" id="duration_use" /></td>
      <td><textarea size="10px" class="form-control" id="watt_hour" style="height: 38px;overflow: hidden;resize: none;"></textarea></td>
      <td><button id="total" class="btn-success btn" style="padding: 5px">Total</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also OP, you may want to do those steps inside the actual click function itself, otherwise the values retrieved will be from when the document.ready function is fired, not when the button is clicked

Comment: @Jhecht Thanks, I have put it in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.text()` with `.val()` and retrive  all the values inside the click event handle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {



  $("#total").click(function() {
    var quantityval = parseInt($("#quantity").val(), 10);
    var wattsval = $("#wattage option:selected").val();
    var duration = parseInt($("#duration_use").val(), 10);

    var totalval = (quantityval * wattsval) * duration;
    console.log(totalval)
    $("#watt_hour").val(totalval);

  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-bordered table table-md text-center table-responsive table-lg" id="table">

  <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Load Type</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Wattage (W)</th>
      <th>Duration Use</th>
      <th>Watt Hour</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="bg-success">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <select class="form-control" id="type">
<option>Fan</option>
<option>Iron</option>
<option>Blub</option>
<option>Motor</option>
<option>AC</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="10px" class="form-control" id="quantity" /></td>
      <td>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="wattage" id="wattage" placeholder="Enter Consumption in Watts" class="form-control"> -->
        <select class="form-control" id="wattage">
<option>25</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>
<option>80</option>
<option>100</option>
<option>120</option>
<option>1000</option>
<option>1500</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>2500</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="10px" class="form-control" id="duration_use" /></td>
      <td><textarea size="10px" class="form-control" id="watt_hour" style="height: 38px;overflow: hidden;resize: none;"></textarea></td>
      <td><button id="total" class="btn-success btn" style="padding: 5px">Total</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```